# Insert statement: Run-time error 3061, too few parameters expected 1

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to insert multiple rows in the table below, but I'm getting this error `Run-time error 3061, too few parameters expected 1` Of course I did something wrong here, but I don't understand what I did wrong.

Table:InstructorAttendance

```
ID         = AutoNumber (long integer)
AttnID     = Number (long integer) pk
IUID       = Number (long integer) not null
AttnDate   = DateTime not null
AttnStatus = Number (long integer)
MS         = Calculated field
MN         = Calculated field
```

The code with which I am trying to insert data is described below:

```
 Private Sub cmdGenerate_Click()
        Dim DateExist As Integer
        Dim Filter As String
        Dim strDate, FD, LD As Date
        Dim NextDate As Date
    
    strDate = CDate(Me.frmMonth & "/" & Me.cboYear)
    
    FD = DateSerial(Year(strDate), Month(strDate), 1)
    LD = DateSerial(Year(strDate), Month(strDate) + 1, 1) - 1
    
    DateExist = DCount("AttnDate", "InstructorAttendance", "AttnDate>=#" & [FD] & "# And AttnDate<=#" & [LD] & "# And IUID=" & Me.[IUID])
    
    If DateExist > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "exist"
    Else
        NextDate = FD
        While DateDiff("d", NextDate, LD) >= 0
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO InstructorAttendance (AttnID, IUID, AttnDate) " & _
                 "Values (" & DMax("AttnID", "InstructorAttendance") + 1 & ", " & Me.IUID & ", NextDate)"
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            NextDate = DateAdd("d", 1, NextDate)
        Wend
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't set `NextDate` before entering the While loop.

Comment: If I don't set `NextDate` before the loop then how can I set the value for `start date`. Maybe I don't understand what you mean. Plz, excuse me.

Comment: I meant "don't" = "haven't" but now I see I was mis-reading it: my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate NextDate variable with # delimiters.

`& ", " & Me.IUID & ", #" & NextDate & "#)"`